How to calculate this integral of error function
We know the Gaussian error function can be defined as $\operatorname{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{s} e^{-t^2} \,\mathrm{d}t$. I wanted to calculate $$\int_0^{\infty} s^2(1-\operatorname{erf}(s)) \, \mathrm{d}s$$I am not sure which properties of the error function to use and how to do the integral. Any help will be appreciated.

Try integration by parts (you know what the derivative of the error function is).

Check your answer ... Maple says $1/(3\sqrt{\pi})$.

Change $2$ by $n$ : one integration by parts gives the antiderivative and the definite integral in terms of $n$

Hints / Overarching Process:

Generally, when you see integrals of the type $\int x^n f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, integration by parts is something to immediately consider. Usually, we would differentiate the $x^n$ here, but since we'd probably struggle to find the integral of $f$ (essentially the error function, itself nonelementary and defined via integral) in the first place, maybe we should swap the order.


Differentiating/Integrating in Integration by Parts: When I say we are differentiating or integrating in integration by parts, I'm thinking most immediately in terms of the tabular method. The function to be differentiated ends up in the "D" column in that method, and the function to be integrated ends up in the "I" column. On the other hand, in the framing $$\int uv' = uv - \int u'v$$ the function being differentiated is $u$ (since it becomes $u'$ on the right hand side) and the function being integrated is $v$. Just wanted to make my verbiage extra clear.


The definition of the error function,
$$
\operatorname{erf}(x) := \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
begs for the use of differentiation. The derivative is easy, thanks to the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Perform integration by parts, differentiating $1-\operatorname{erf}x$ and integrating $x^2$ in that process, and see what arises.

Note that $\operatorname{erf}(x) \xrightarrow{x\to\infty} 1$ and $\operatorname{erf}(0) = 0$. (These are immediate from the definition, and will be used in the evaluation of the integration by parts.) The integral that remains should be easily solved with the substitution $u=x^2$ and more integration by parts.



Thanks I did it.
